# Frequency of all substrings

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I want to find frequency of all substrings in a string in C++. Currently I am using the following :

```
    unordered_map<string,int> mp;
    string s;// the string of which we want all substrings... n is length
    cin>>s;
    string t;
    for(int i=0,i<=n-1;++i) // starting point of a substring
    {
        t="";
        for(int j=i;j<=n-1;++j) // all substrings startings at i
        {
            t+=s[j];
            ++mp[t];
        }
    }
```

I want to improve its time complexity. Can we do any better? Does there exist a better algorithm? Sorry if this is not on topic here... I will close it if that's the case.

**Edit :**

Here's what I came up with... Maintain a trie of all suffixes of the string. Then traverse all the substrings starting at i so that searching is O(1).

Each node specifies a substring(prefix of suffix). Now maintain frequency at each node and update it accordingly. Though this method is O(n^2) but the constants are fairly large due to memory allocation and resetting each next pointers of node(26 times) to NULL. Can I optimize it further? Also can there be any faster alternatives to store a trie than a linked list? I was able to squeeze my solution but it was very close to the time limit.

Comment: What is `v` in `++mp[v];`?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tsuki that should be t... lemme edit that

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: @BrentWashburne No, not in it's actual form. They want to have complete compilable code IIRC.

Comment: Search for suffix tree, it will help.

Comment: It seems to me you're really looking for high-level advice on algorithms rather than a low-level code review.

Comment: When you profiled the code, which lines were the bottlenecks?

Comment: @DavidK  Yes... I thought the code would be better than the algo here

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I didn't really profile the code... I just checked its time without ++mp[t] and it was pretty less.

Comment: What's the context? Why are you doing this? There might be a better approach altogether.

Comment: Posts at http://codereview.stackexchange.com are expected to be correctly running programs. Don't post just code fragments there.

Comment: It looks like there should be an algorithm with much lower asymptotic complexity, related somehow to a trie or a suffix tree. But you would need to add frequency data to the structure.

Comment: @Baldrick I need to compute it to solve a competitive programming problem. I don't want to ask the whole problem. I just want to know this part.

Comment: No, don't delete this question.  It's started a good discussion!

Comment: You just hide all necessary information, if it is a competitive programming problem, show us the problem statement, and how do you think you should solve it.

Comment: @PhamTrung If I am unable to solve it, I will ask that as a separate question. For now, I just want to know how to compute this part as fast as I can... This will help me if I encounter a problem in future.

Comment: Check out this internet [search - algorithm generate substrings and frequency](https://www.google.com/search?q=algorithm+generate+substrings+and+frequency&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that in some sense you can do it in O(n) with a suffix tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree (and maybe similar data structures can also work, e.g. suffix automata, suffix array, etc.) As there are total O(n^2) substrings, you'll have to condense the result a bit to achieve O(n) time: suffix tree can tell you the count `n` of all substrings starting at index `i`, with lengths from `a` to `b`. There will be only O(n) such groups of substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version in raw C code.  It uses two arrays that are the same length as the input string (`s_len`) to count the number of matches and the position of duplicates.  The advantage is that the string is never duplicated in a map, and it saves the time needed to create map entries (which you found was much slower).  Another advantage is that it doesn't require n^2 memory, it prints out the information immediately like a map/reduce function, to be processed in a later step.  It uses native C memory functions like `calloc()`, `bzero()` and `memcmp()` for efficient memory allocation, zeroing and comparing.

The algorithm works like this:

- For each string of length `len`, as `len` goes from 1 to `s_len`-1:
- Clear out the arrays `matches` and `dups`;
- Walk along the string (using `i`) from the start (position 0) to the end:
- If this position was already counted as a duplicate, skip it;
- For each position further down the string (`j` = `i+1` to `stop`), compare it with the current position;
- If this is a match, increment the number of matches at position `i` and mark position `j` as a duplicate;
- At the end of this walk, print out the number of matches for length `len`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    /* for calloc() */
#include <strings.h>   /* for bzero() */

/* Find the number of matching substrings in the string s */
void sub(char *s)
{
    size_t s_len = strlen(s);
    short *matches = (short *) calloc(s_len, sizeof(short));
    short *dups = (short *) calloc(s_len, sizeof(short));
    size_t n = s_len * sizeof(short);    /* used by bzero() */
    size_t len, i, j, stop;

    /* Find all substrings of length 1..s_len */
    for (len=1; len<s_len; ++len)
    {
        bzero((void *) matches, n);    /* zero out the number of matches */
        bzero((void *) dups, n);       /* zero out the duplicates */
        stop = s_len - len + 1;
        for (i=0; i<stop; ++i)
        {   
            if (dups[i])    /* this is a duplicate (was already counted) */
                continue;   
            for (j=i+1; j<stop; ++j)
            {       
                if (memcmp(s+i, s+j, len))    /* substring comparison */
                    continue;    /* not a match? continue */
                matches[i]++;
                dups[j] = 1;
            }       
            if (matches[i])
                printf("%d: %.*s\n", matches[i]+1, (int) len, s+i);
        }   
    }
}

int main()
{
    sub("abcabcabcabc");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
4: a
4: b
4: c
4: ab
4: bc
3: ca
4: abc
3: bca
3: cab
3: abca
3: bcab
3: cabc
3: abcab
3: bcabc
2: cabca
3: abcabc
2: bcabca
2: cabcab
2: abcabca
2: bcabcab
2: cabcabc
2: abcabcab
2: bcabcabc
2: abcabcabc
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way. Imagine your string is 10 characters long, and all characters are different:

```
`0123456789`
```

In this case, all substrings are unique. So there are O(n^2) unique substrings. Each substring needs its own entry in the dictionary. To be precise, (n^2)/2 = 50 entries in this case.

So to insert those substrings in the dictionary will take at least 50 insert operations.

So certainly in the general case, there's not much that can be done to avoid an upper bound of O(n^2).

Concentrate on making the code itself faster - I'm not sure you'll find a better algorithm.

Comment: @PhamTrung If I use a map it will be O(n^2*log(n)) Can we do it in O(n^2) ?

Comment: Also, now I read that += operation in string has time complexity linear to size of new string. Can we improve on that part?

Comment: @Awesome no, when you use a map, it will call string comparison when insert, and total time complexity is O(n^3 log(n)).

Comment: @PhamTrung Should I read suffix trees in order to build a O(n^2) algo?

Comment: @Awesome as Baldrick prove here, an O(n^2) is the best you can do, so suffix tree seems to be one of your best option.

Comment: @Awesome: Intuitively, this seems like a suffix tree problem, but I don't quite see the solution yet. It's interesting that you can build a suffix tree in O(n) even though it (implicitly) contains O(n^2) substrings. You should be able to leverage that to create a much faster algorithm.

Comment: YOu can't do much about the upper bound. But don't give up yet. It you're dealing with non-random strings you can do much better than the upper bound. Consider the string FOODOOFOODOO, once you get the all the substrings for FOODOO, you can just double them for the second FOODOO. You don't have to re-traverse it.

Comment: I've tried your code with a random string of 5000 characters. Compiled in 64 bit mode, it runs for over 5 minutes before slowing right down and pretty much killing my machine. Swallows up 6GB of RAM and tons of virtual memory. So it can't be used in its current state for your purposes, that's for sure.